# Create a Woocommerce custom template with product filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a custom template where I want to show the product feed with some filters.

This is the code I'm using to display the product loop:

```
    <ul class="products">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'product_cat' => $product_category
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($loop->have_posts()) {
                while ($loop->have_posts()):
                    $loop->the_post();
                    wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
                endwhile;
            } else {
                echo __('No products found');
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
    </ul>
```

How can I create the filters to let the user choose products attributes? (for ex. colors, tag)

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. You could write custom JS/AJAX, you could use the FacetWP plugin - there are several ways to do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with a couple of plugins, but they don't recognize my loop

Answer (score 1):

The Filter Everything plugin should work. It allows you to easily create filters based on categories, tags, custom taxonomies, product attributes, acf fields, etc.

I believe you can use a shortcode or drop a widget where you want the filters, like in the side bar, and set what container has your loop.

You can copy and customize the template parts, like the radio button layout or the checkbox layout, and apply each set of filters the layout you want.

For instance you can set up radio buttons for category and checkboxes for tags, a drop down for size, and swatches for color, all styled how you want.